# How to create "certificateKeyFile" for mongodb from wildcard domain certificate?

Tags: mongodb, ssl

I trying to setup a secure connection to mongodb server.

To make things work I need to provide `certificateKeyFile` to `mongod.conf` config file.

I know that I need to concatenate some files to obtain `certificateKeyFile`. **But which ones?**

The files I've got (wildcard domain certificate):

- authorityCertificates.ca-bundle
- domainCertificate.crt
- request.csr
- private.key

I've setup `mongod.conf` according to [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl/#set-up-mongod-and-mongos-with-tls-ssl-certificate-and-key)

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1, 42.42.42.42
  tls:
    mode: requireTLS
    certificateKeyFile: /etc/mongodb.pem
```

I've concatenated `domainCertificate.crt` and `private.key` to obtain `mongodb.pem` and when I try to connect to the database with:

```
mongo 42.42.42.42 --tls --tlsCAFile ./authorityCertificates.ca-bundle
```

I get this:

```
SL peer certificate validation failed:
unable to get issuer certificate
```

My basic understanding is that when a client connects to a `MongoDB` server it's presented with a domain certificate signed by an authority certificate. After that the client takes the authority certificate and verifies the validity of the domain certificate. If the domain certificate is verified the server and the client establish a secure connection.

What am I missing?

Comment: Link to server documentation where this option is described please.

Comment: @D.SM, this is the closest [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl/#set-up-mongod-and-mongos-with-client-certificate-validation) I could find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yay, I've made it work.

- pointed DNS A Record for **mongodb.mydomain.com** to 42.42.42.42
- created **mongodb.pem** file and uploaded it to mongodb server

```
cat ./authorityCertificates.ca-bundle ./domainCertificate.crt > ./chained.pem
cat ./chained.pem ./private.key > mongodb.pem
```

- sucessfully connected to **mongodb** on remote machine

```
mongo mongodb.mydomain.com --tls
```